# Looking for name of combinatorial problem- Permute rows and columns to minimize distance to target matrix

Tags: optimization, algorithms, np-complete, extremal-combinatorics, matching-theory

I am trying to find a solution (or algorithm) for the following combinatorial problem:

Given an input matrix and a target matrix, find a permutation of the rows and permutation of the columns that minimizes some (predefined) distance between the two matrices.

For example, I have an input matrix 
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 1 & 0\\  
2 & 4 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

and a target matrix

\begin{pmatrix}
5 & 0 & 0\\ 
1 & 2 & 1\\ 
3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}

and I want to minimize the element-wise distance between the input matrix I and the target matrix T $\sum_{i}^{n} \sum_{j}^{n} \left | i_{ij} - t_{ij}\right |$

as an example here is a permutation of the rows
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 & 0\\  
2 & 4 & 1\\
4 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}

and here is a permutation of the columns (after the permutation of the rows)

\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 & 1\\  
2 & 1 & 4\\
4 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}

I would be really grateful towards anyone who can point me towards literature for solving this problem.

Comment: Given two graphs presented as (0,1)-adjacency matrices, the graphs are isomorphic iff the rows and columns of one matrix can be permuted so that it is equivalent to the other.  This means graph isomorphism is contained within your problem as a special case, so your problem can't be any easier in general. My gut feeling is that your problem is going to turn out to be NP-hard.

Comment: Related question for graph isomorphism: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/518436/normalizing-a-matrix-with-row-and-column-swapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm that usually reduces, but does not minimize, the distance.

Permute $I$ and $T$ as per the algorithm $f()$ described below:

1. Calculate the multisets of each row

   e.g. 
   \begin{pmatrix}
   4 & 2 & 3\\
   4 & 1 & 0\\  
   2 & 4 & 1
   \end{pmatrix}
   becomes
   $(2,3,4),(0,1,4),(1,2,4)$
2. Sort the rows based on the lexicographical order of the multisets

   e.g.
   $(2,3,4),(0,1,4),(1,2,4)$

   becomes

   $(0,1,4),(1,2,4),(2,3,4)$
3. Calculate the multisets of each column
4. Sort the columns based on the lexicographical order of the multisets

The output of this algorithm is $f(I)∘f`(T)$.